# Create total element based value that have same value in array php

Tags: php

I have an array like this on php :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CONSIGNEE] => PT. XX
        [CONTAINER] => DFSU1587848

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CONSIGNEE] => PT. YYY
        [CONTAINER] => TEMU2365554
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [CONSIGNEE] => PT. ZZZ
        [CONTAINER] => CBHU5788073

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [CONSIGNEE] => PT. HHH
        [CONTAINER] => CBHU5788073
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [CONSIGNEE] => PT. OOO
        [CONTAINER] => CBHU3884376
    )
)
```

Please see in element CONTAINER.

How can I know that on those array just have 4 item container, which is,

```
DFSU1587848, TEMU2365554, CBHU5788073, CBHU3884376.
```

If php have a built function like that ?

Comment: I could be understanding you wrong but won't `if (count($array) == 4) {` do what you want?

Comment: I just wanna to say to user, that you have 4 container. I just need this letter "4"

Answer (score 2):

```
$containers = array_unique(array_column($data, 'CONTAINER'));
$count = count($containers);
```

1. [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) gets a column in a 2-dimensional array.
2. [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) removes duplicates from the array.
3. [`count`](http://php.net/count) counts all the elements in the array.

Comment: Thanks, it so helpfull for beginner like me

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking - from what I understand, you wish to create an array with the `CONTAINER` values in this array.

You can do this by looping through the array and adding those values to a new array, like so:

```
//Set up new array
$containers = [];

//Loop through existing array
foreach($array as $a){

    //See if this array has a "container" key
    if($a["CONTAINER"]){

        //Push the new Container value to the $containers array
        $containers[] = $a["CONTAINER"];

    }

}

//Output the finished product
print_r($containers);
```

Once this is done, to count the number of elements with the `CONTAINER` key:

```
$num = count($containers);
```

---

For just the count of `CONTAINER` keys:

```
$n = 0;
foreach($array as $a){
    if($a["container"]) $n++;
}

echo $n;
```

Comment: I just wanna to say to user, that you have 4 container. I just need this letter "4"

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `array_map` for that:

```
$yourArray = [
    ['x' => 'a', 'CONTAINER' => 'aa'],
    ['x' => 'a', 'CONTAINER' => 'bb'],
    ['x' => 'a', 'CONTAINER' => 'cc'],
    ['x' => 'a', 'CONTAINER' => 'aa'],
    ['x' => 'a', 'CONTAINER' => 'aa'],
    ['x' => 'a', 'CONTAINER' => 'bb'],
];


$arr = array_unique(array_map(function($x){ return $x['CONTAINER']; }, $yourArray));
echo (count($arr));
```

Itt will echos 3.

Answer (score 0):

To get all `CONTAINER` values do the following:

```
$key = 'CONTAINER';
$containers = array_map(function($item) use ($key) {
    return $item[$key];
}, $array);

print_r($containers);
```

If you just want to know how much `CONTAINER` values there are, do a `count()` after the above code.

```
echo count($containers);
```